# Fetching everything from a table and storing it in an array

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-bot-service

I'm working on a chatbot built using the Microsoft Bot Framework that fetches its answers from Azure Table where it's stored as JSON objects. Once the Node.js code runs, it fetches everything from an `answers` table and stores it in an array. The rest of the code uses this array to fetch its data.

I was wondering if will run into any limitations in the future? Will the array become too big if it stores too many answers etc? Currently the table holds about 60 answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the limitations for the Azure Table storage on this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-scalability-targets#azure-table-storage-scale-targets

It mentions the bellow: 
[image]

You'll have to keep answers below 1 MiB and the full table under 500 TiB.